# Way to disable "System" service or process for a short period of time? Python

Tags: python, windows, service, process

I'm not sure if it is a service or process, but is there a way to disable it or stop it? A file which I'm trying to copy is being run by the system but the system does not require this .sys file.

If there is way in python I would be even more ecstatic to read the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, if Windows says that it needs a file, you will be very hard pressed to get it to completely relinquish control. While that process is running, it will have exclusive rights (read, write, and execute) to the file (or files) in question, so I will highly doubt that there will be an effective hack while running Windows.

My personal suggestion would be to get a live boot disk so that you can run Linux off of either a USB or an optical drive. Boot into the alternate OS, copy the file, and then be on your merry way.

Comment: But later i need to replace the file i'm talking about with the same file that i copied but with different data in it.

Comment: If Windows is locking the file, then the only way to modify the file is to make sure you aren't using that particular install of Windows.

Comment: this works perfectly with ubuntu...what live cd do you sugjest maybe thats smaller ive already tried dsl and knopix...neither of them work :(